# node_redis: is SMEMBERS blocking?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Under Redis's [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) documentation, it mentions this about [SMEMBERS](http://redis.io/commands/smembers):

> However while blocking commands like SMEMBERS are able to provide all the elements that are part of a Set in a given moment, The SCAN family of commands only offer limited guarantees about the returned elements since the collection that we incrementally iterate can change during the iteration process.

Surprisingly, I can't find any additional information about how SMEMBERS is blocking and when to avoid using it.  If SMEMBERS is a blocking call, is it safe to use in [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) or will blocking Redis end up blocking Node's thread as well?

Slightly related, if [SSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/sscan) is the best practice instead of calling SMEMBERS, is there an equivalent SCAN call for [SINTER](http://redis.io/commands/sinter)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all of Redis' commands are blocking, `SCAN` included (it guarantees short execution time however). The only commands that are non-blocking are those performed by other threads (currently persistence-related only, e.g. BGSAVE).

Specifically, `SMEMBERS` is blocking. This can be ok if your Set isn't too large (a few K's perhaps(. If the Set becomes too large, Redis will block while preparing the reply and will consume a RAM to buffer it before sending it back. In such cases, iterating through the Set with `SSCAN` is advisable to allow other requests interleave between calls to it.